# Audio Chipset for 2011 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a 13-inch Macbook Pro from late 2011 and recently upgraded it to macOS Mojave using this patcher tool: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/. It has some preinstalled kext files that make the Mac work properly, but not everything works perfectly.

One of the main problems is that the built-in speakers are not being discovered by the computer. I tried plugging in headphones, but that didn't work either. I did a bit of research and found a kext file that might do the job, but I would need to find what audio chip the Mac uses.

If anyone knows what chipset the 2011 Macbook Pro has, or know another way to fix this issue, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Does the headphone port work as expected?

Comment: The headphone jack worked with High Sierra, but when I updated the computer to Mojave, the operating system was not able to detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jean_JD's comment, I was able to go the sound working on my Mac. I reloaded the patches, without having to reinstall macOS Mojave. The sound now works, without having to install additional kext files. Again, thank you Jean_JD for helping!

Comment: With pleasure and good luck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can try is doing a [Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

Comment: I tried doing that, but that’s not the problem. I installed macOS Mojave on a computer that is not compatible with that operating system, so hardware like the audio chipset is not being recognized by the computer. There are kext files that are able to patch that problem, and my question is how I would get them installed and configured with the chipset in the Mac.

Comment: I've install Catalina on a MBP 13"  Early 2011 using Dosdude patch and I've no problem with audio.  In the "Mac OS PostInstall screen" http://dosdude1.com/mojave/tutorialimages/step11.png have you check "Legacy Audio Patch"?